# Does half real line $\Omega$ = $[0,\infty)$ satisfy the cone condition?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

Some hints to prove it, because I want to know whether I can use the Sobolev embedding theorem for this domain  $\Omega$ = $[0,\infty)$ or not.

(The Cone Condition) : $\Omega$ satisfies the cone condition if there exists a
finite cone C such that each x $\in \Omega  $ is the vertex of a finite cone $C_{x}$ contained in $\Omega$ and congruent to C. Note that $C_{x}$ need not be obtained from C by parallel translation, but simply by rigid motion.

Sobolev Imbedding Theorem I want to use :

Let $\Omega$ be a domain
in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ an  Let $0\leq j$ and $1\leq m$ be integers and let
$1\leq p\leq \infty$. Suppose that $\Omega$  satisfies the cone condition  then :
if either $n<mp$ or $m=n$ and $p=1$ then, :
$$W^{j+m,p}(\Omega) \rightarrow  C^{j}_{B}(\Omega)$$

Here $W^{j+m,p}(\Omega)$ is a Sobolev space  and $C^{j}_{B}$ is the space of j-times continuously differentiable and bounded functions on  $\Omega$

In My case , $\Omega$ = $[0,\infty)$ , j=0 , p=1 and m=1   i.e the sobolev space $H^{1}([0,\infty))

Comment: This condition is trivially satisfied with $C=(0,1)$.